# CefSettings giving error or not working in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have made a browser in c# wpf using cefsharp, but the problem is that, I want to change my user agent and Improve the quality like chrome(Because my browser is laggy). I researched alot to find the solution. I used CefSettings, But it either gave errors or It would not work.

```
 public MainWindow()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
        var s = new CefSettings();
        s.UserAgent = "my user agnt ";
        Cef.Initialize(s);
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?
I am not using new ChromiumWebBrowser()
I am using xaml:

```
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser TitleChanged="main_TitleChanged" AddressChanged="main_AddressChanged" x:Name="main" Address="http://www.google.com" Grid.Row="1">
          
    </cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser>
```

Comment: You need to call Cef.Initialize before the first ChromiumWebBrowser instance is created. Move your code before InitializeComponent(). It's unlikely changing the user agent will change the performance characteristics. If you don't need transparency switch to https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf.HwndHost/

Comment: Hi, @amaitland for your help but in `this.container.add(chrome)` is is giving errors

Comment: Please edit your original question and provide a detailed example and a copy of the exception. No images please.